# How to set Depenency Property propertymetadata to LinearGradientBrush in C# WPF (in runtime)?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, datagrid, wpf-controls

I have a custom `UserControl` called TemplateButton. I am tried many ways to set `PropertyMetadata` to `LinearGradientBrush`, but nothing seems to help. So any solutions?

```
public LinearGradientBrush myProperty
        {
            get { return (LinearGradientBrush)GetValue(myPropertyProperty); }
            set { SetValue(myPropertyProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for myProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty myPropertyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("myProperty", typeof(LinearGradientBrush), typeof(TemplateButton), new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

or just

```
new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

What i need to use instead of `0`?

Comment: Consider using the more general type Brush instead of LinearGradientBrush.

Answer (score 1):

The default value of any [mutable reference type](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bc%23%5d%20mutable%20reference%20type) dependency property should be `null`.

Otherwise multiple instances of the owning class could potentially operate on the same default-value object, which may lead to unexpected behaviour.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty myPropertyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(myProperty),
        typeof(LinearGradientBrush),
        typeof(TemplateButton),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Ideally, do not set any PropertyMetadata at all unless you really need to:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty myPropertyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(myProperty),
        typeof(LinearGradientBrush),
        typeof(TemplateButton));
```

Comment: Thanks for fast reply, i don't still understand lol
P.S. Bad english

Edit: Oh my bad, now i understand when i tried 89213901h time